# Excel VBA to iSeries Error 25202 - Unable to open the key file

Tags: vba, ssl, connection, ibm-midrange, adodb

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to get data off of iSeries Databases using IBM Access Client Solutions. I'm getting a CWBC01034 - SSL Error 25202 (Unable to open the key file. Either the path was specified incorrectly or the file permissions did not allow the file to be opened). How do I know where it's looking for this key file? What do we need to change in our connection sting to make the connections work and find the proper key?

Our connection string currently is: ConnectString = "Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;System=;UID=;Pwd=;MGDSN=0;SSL=1;"

Comment: can you login to the system using SSH from a terminal prompt?  `ssh username@ipddress`

Comment: Hello - Yes, I just and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Sorry - that's not accurate - I actually get the following...  -W gen   Generator to use for generating DH-GEX moduli.